# PHP : Parsing asp page

Tags: php, parsing, xml-parsing, html-parsing

Can somebody please help me for parsing data from URL containing asp page.

http://www.bseindia.com/mktlive/mktwatch.asp

I want to retrieve all the data from this URL using php.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   echo file_get_contents("http://www.bseindia.com/mktlive/mktwatch.asp");
?>
```

Simple as that. Then use DOM to parse that data.

Comment: can you please explain in details? i am not as technically sound for this one.

Comment: This way you can grab all the data that is being shown on that url. Then you can write some code to parse your required data from that. If you have no clue about how to do so, unfortunately we won't be able to help much. You have to be able to demonstrate a little more than a minimal understanding of how to solve this specific problem.

Comment: actually this one echo nothing , that's why i have ask you